# Is it possible to automate tests on an embedded WebKit browser on Mac OS X?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, browser-automation, test-automation-framework, uiautomation

Is it possible to automate the tests on a [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)/WebView browser that is embedded in a Mac OS X desktop application, preferably using [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) or some Mac-based tool like [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) or Automator?

I'm unable to figure out automating an embedded browser on Mac, though we have done it for a Windows/CEF combination.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [*Comparison of GUI testing tools*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_GUI_testing_tools) may be a helpful reference.  It lists a handful of tools capable of automating at the browser level or OS level.  Note that this list is not specific to Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) can be an option:

Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

Comment: It seems that sikuli has been [deprecated](https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli/blob/develop/README.md) in favor of [sikulix](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1).

Answer (score 0):

Check if Squish tool can help you.

Squish is GUI automation framework they support macOS application with embedded WebKit.

Comment: No Comment needed. Instead of adding single line answer, Please explain some more details how Squish tool can help us in embedded WebKit browser? Add reference Links,  If you have.

Comment: Squish detects the HTML components inside an embedded `WebView` resp. `WKWebView` control. You can access the HTML objects and query their properties, as well as doing interactions on them (like clicking on a link or entering text into an `<input>` element).

Comment: More info on Squish ([website](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/), [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squish_(Froglogic))): It is a long-standing commercial product made by a company called Froglogic.  It supports property-based object identification and recording and playback using test scripts written in several common languages.  It supports macOS, *nix, Windows, etc.

Comment: Squish also appears to be extremely expensive (over $1000 per user per year), and closed source, or at least I cannot seem to find the source available publicly anywhere.  https://www.froglogic.com/squish/prices/named-user-licensing/